# Finding an identity for set difference using intersection and symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Suppes "Axiomatic Set Theory", chapter 2, section 2.3, question 12h:

"Find an identity which will serve as a definition of difference in terms of symmetric difference and intersection".

Is my solution correct?
$A\cap(A\div B)=A\sim B$
I proved it as such:

$x\in A\cap(A\div B)\iff (x\in A) \land [(x\in A \land x\notin B)\lor (x \in B \land x\notin A)]$.

Using distributive law of sentenial logic i obtain:
$(x\in A \land x\notin B)\lor(x\in A\land x \notin A \land x\in B)$

The second formula yields the empty set and the first is $A\sim B$.
So i get:
$(A\sim B)\cup\emptyset=A\sim B$.
Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_set_identities_and_relations#Two_sets_involved

$L \setminus R = L \triangle (L \cap R)$ or also $L \setminus R = L \cap (L \triangle R)$ where the triangle denotes symmetric difference.

Your formula is the second one and your reasoning is correct although I would write "The right-most expression is always false" instead of "The second formula yields the empty set".

Comment: Thank you very much.